# hibernate with spring-boot does not release the connection after a org.hibernate.ScrollableResults

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, java-8

Goodmorning everyone,

I have an Soap Endpoint built via SpringBoot 1.5.8.RELEASE (java 8) that connects to a database ORACLE12C and returns some data sets. For some methods I used JpaRepository while for other queries I created the query via javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder instantiated via javax.persistence.EntityManager.getCriteriaBuilder() (EntityManager is @Autowired via spring).

I noticed that, once the 100 requests were exceeded, the connection pool stopped making connections (***[http-nio-80-exec-4] Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 30 seconds, none available[size:100; busy:100; idle:0; lastwait:30000].***) in a particular case: the case in which 100 requests had been executed involving an object of type org.hibernate.ScrollableResults.

```
ScrollableResults scroll = em.createQuery(cq).setHint(QueryHints.HINT_FETCH_SIZE, max).unwrap(org.hibernate.Query.class).scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
List<Document> list = new ArrayList<>(max);
for (int i = 0; scroll.next() && i < max; i++) {
    list.add((Document) scroll.get(0));
}
scroll.close();
```

after reading around some examples and documentation that did not lead to the solution, I did a test trying to translate the code as follows:

```
List<Document> list = em.createQuery(cq).setFirstResult(0).setMaxResults(max).getResultList();
```

and all works fine; however I need to keep the "scroll" mode and all the various experiments have failed.

I tried to play with the "spring.datasource.tomcat" properties without success.

can someone help me ?

Comment: What JDBC pool are you using? Maybe there is a problem with the pool implementation?

Comment: @Strelok I did not specify anything, so it is the Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool, as I read from the official documentation, in fact the property that I configured to do the tests ( spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait: 1000 ) works as I expected

Comment: Too little information to know what the problem is. How are you creating the entity manager? Have you tried to get the connection from the entity manager and call close explicitly? You need to do some debugging.

Comment: @Strelok i didn't create anything manually, it's all on spring-boot. EM is create by SpringBoot autowired in my endpoint via Autowired annotation. I didn't define any bean exept a ConfigurationProperties for my own parameters, all beans are from SpringBoot !

Comment: I would try using another pool. Like HikariCP